# Synchronized Arraylist between two threads doesn't return the same value

Tags: java, multithreading

I have following code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class MyThread implements Runnable{

    private List<Integer> myList;

    public MyThread(List<Integer> list){
            this.myList = list;
    }
    private void updateList(int i){
           synchronized (myList) {
               myList.add(i);
           }
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for( int i = 0; i < 1000000;i++){
                updateList(i);
        }
        System.out.println("end: " + myList.size());
    }
}
public class MyExecutor {

    private List<Integer> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    private void launch(){

        ExecutorService executorService= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10000);
        executorService.execute(new MyThread(taskList));
        executorService.execute(new MyThread(taskList));
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyExecutor test = new MyExecutor();
        test.launch();
    }
}
```

the output should be : **2000000**

I will get different result which means these two threads are replacing each other's value.

I can't figure out where is the problem, tried several modifications on this code but none of them has fixed the problem. (replaced with Vector / added synchronize in constructor / added volatile)

Why doesn't this code work correctly?

Edit

**At both thread I expect to get 1000000**

Comment: Try printing the size after both threads have finished.

Comment: at both thread I expect to get 1M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting

```
end: 1065878
end: 2000000
```

The first line is from the thread that has finished its job first. It shouldn't be exactly `1M`, because several threads are working. It's reasonable to assume that by the time one first thread finishes adding its `1M`, the other has added at least one.

The second line is always `2M` (as you expected ) due to the synchronised method.

> I guess the first thread should execute for the exact number I wanted, no more no less.

Things happened in parallel. The threads were running. Each was trying to invoke `updateList`: one entered, the others waited. There was no priority on who should be next, so the control over the method was being passed among all the workers in a rather random manner.

I bet you are still thinking of the sequential execution :) One thread runs the whole `run` method, prints `1M`, the other takes a 1M-sized list and adds its portion.

To understand it better, add a print statement

```
private void updateList(int i) {
    synchronized (myList) {
        myList.add(i);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " added " + i);
    }
}
```

and reduce the number of elements to add by a task to, let's say, `10`.

```
pool-1-thread-1 added 0
pool-1-thread-1 added 1
pool-1-thread-1 added 2
pool-1-thread-1 added 3
pool-1-thread-2 added 0
pool-1-thread-2 added 1
pool-1-thread-2 added 2
pool-1-thread-2 added 3
pool-1-thread-1 added 4
pool-1-thread-1 added 5
pool-1-thread-1 added 6
pool-1-thread-1 added 7
pool-1-thread-1 added 8
pool-1-thread-1 added 9
end: 14
pool-1-thread-2 added 4
pool-1-thread-2 added 5
pool-1-thread-2 added 6
pool-1-thread-2 added 7
pool-1-thread-2 added 8
pool-1-thread-2 added 9
end: 20
```

Comment: I guess the first thread should execute for the exact number I wanted, no more no less.

Comment: It DOES! But the other thread added elements too. First print can give you anything between 1000000 and 200000. Second print will always be exactly 2000000.

Comment: Minor detail: There are 10 000 threads allowed actually. There are two jobs (Runnables) only though. So only two will ever be used.

Answer (score 3):

> the output should be : 2000000

No, for three reasons:

1. You are printing two things, so the output won't be a single number.
2. It prints the size when each thread happens to have added 1000000 things; you know nothing about how much the other thread has done at this point.
3. You are not accessing the size in a synchronized way, so you are liable to get a non-up to date value.

Comment: is that what you mean?                                                                                           synchronized (myList) {
            System.out.println("end: " + myList.size());
        }

Comment: @Vahidhashemi Not accessing size() synchroinously can only give you the result off by 1 am I wrong?

Comment: For the 1st point, wait for both to finish. Can be accomplished with this: ´executorService.awaitTermination(...)´  and then after that print the final size.

Comment: "It prints the size when each thread happens to have added 1000000 things; you know nothing about how much the other thread has done at this point." Well second print should be right though.

Comment: Second print is correct, but I expect the first to be correct too

Comment: @MattiasIsegranBergander yes, provided you access the size with appropriate synchronization.

Comment: Not needed in this case @AndyTurner actually, but that's out of scope for this question (tryTerminate in impl will use the internal reentrant lock causing synchronization).

Comment: synchronising `size()` won't change things much: it still would be a number between 1M and 2M telling nothing